# Hover with anchor tag is not persisted

Tags: protractor

When I try to hover a hyperlink- ( anchor tag ) through automation using `protractor in Chrome`, I observed that hovering is not persisted. I can see the mouse over event but then it immediately stops and it is not waiting until the next action to perform because after hovering I need to verify a tool tip.

As mouse over is not waiting for the next action, I'm not able to verify the tool tip. I'm able to click the anchor tag but facing issue with hovering.

The code snippet that I used is

```
browser.sleep( 5000 );

var ele = element( by.xpath( '//tf-infobox//[normalize-space(.)="Error 1"]/following-sibling:://a' ) );

browser.actions().mouseMove( ele ).perform();

browser.sleep( 5000 );
```

- Node Version: 4.2.2
- Protractor Version: 3.1.1
- Chrome Version: 52.0
- Chrome driver version: 2.21

Additional Info: Hovering issue is seen only for hyperlink - anchor tag but not for the other elements.

Can someone help me out to solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the Website?

Comment: Protractor 2.14?..

Comment: @alecxe I am sorry the protractor version I used is 3.1.1

Comment: @KishanPatel I am sorry I can not able to share the website because it is the restrcited one.

Comment: browser.actions().movetoelement( ele ).build().perform();

Try this and use the latest protractor version.

Comment: @KishanPatel I am getting error saying moveToElement is not a function when I try to use the way you suggested.

Comment: @KishanPatel I tried to run with protractor latest version as well, still it gives the same issue. And one more thing I observed that when my physical mouse pointer is on browser window that got launched through automation as soon as run gets triggered the hovering functionality is persisted but when my physical mouse pointer focus is not on browser that launched through automation everything looks fine and not getting any issues.

Comment: It is very simple dear. I have used it many times. Without Website I'm helpless.

Comment: I found a solution for this. I used jquery command in the scripts like browser.driver.executeScript( '$('tf-infobox tf-spotlight:contains('Error 1') a').mouseover(); ' ); There are some issues with dropdowns and inputs as well but when I use jquery commands in the scripts they worked for me. So I am guessing with the latest version of webdriver there are some issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this.

I used jquery command in the scripts like

browser.driver.executeScript( '$('tf-infobox tf-spotlight:contains('Error 1') a').mouseover(); ' );

There are some issues with dropdowns and inputs as well but when I use jquery commands in the scripts they worked for me. So I am guessing with the latest version of webdriver there are some issues

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar test for a tooltip, and I use `browser.wait(tooltip.isPresent(),5000)` to wait until the tooltip is added to the DOM before I check its contents.

Comment: I have added wait time and sleep time as well still no use. When I monitor the run I can see the hovering action but after hover mouse pointer is not waiting its just moving after hover within seconds.